# Prime React Chart Axios data does not load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, primereact

I try to load data in a graph using a rest api, but it doesn't load for some reason,
can you help me

this is the data that the api brings
{
"avg_soc_fleet": 74.85
}

here is the code

```
const Rem = () => {

    const [avgSoc, SetAvgSoc] = useState({});
    

    



    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/other/avgsoc_fleet').then(response => {
            SetAvgSoc(response.data);

        })

        

    }, []);

   

    
    const [avgChart] = useState({
        labels: ['Soc', 'Pressure', 'Isolation', 'BattVolt24'],

        datasets: [
            {
               
                data: [Object.values(avgSoc)],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#4bc0c0',
                tension: .4
            },


        ]
    });

    const options = {
        legend: {
            display: true,
        }
    };



    return (
        <div className="grid">
            <div className="col-8">
                <div className="card">
                    <Chart type="line" data={avgChart} options={options} />


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Rem;
```

render chart
I hope I can load the data from the api in the graph in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the avgChart after getting the response from axios. In that case avgSoc seems unnecessary, try the following:

```js
const Rem = () => {
  const [avgChart, setAvgChart] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/other/avgsoc_fleet').then(response => {
        const chartOptions={
          labels: ['Soc', 'Pressure', 'Isolation', 'BattVolt24'],
      
          datasets: [
              {
                 
                  data: [Object.values(response.data)],
                  fill: false,
                  borderColor: '#4bc0c0',
                  tension: .4
              },
      
      
          ]
      }
      setAvgChart(chartOptions);

      })

      

  }, []);

 

  
  

  const options = {
      legend: {
          display: true,
      }
  };



  return (
      <div className="grid">
          <div className="col-8">
              <div className="card">
                  <Chart type="line" data={avgChart} options={options} />


              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default Rem;
```

**OBS: This is an example of how to proceed, not necessarily the only possible implementation.**

Comment: thakns it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the data, you need to update the `avgChart` again. use a setState method

```
const [avgChart, setAvgChart] = useState({
```

add new useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(avgSoc.length){

          setAvgChart({
             ...avgChart,
             datasets: {
                ...avgChart.datasets
                data: [Object.values(avgSoc)], 
             }
          })
    }

    

}, [avgSoc]);
```